# Rewrite single template permalink?

Tags: permalinks, templates, url-rewriting

I have a single template file called `single-schools.php`. A school "templated" post is reached via the url http://example.com/schools/post. But the site's main language is Swedish, and therefore I want the permalink to be `/skolor/post` instead. I wanna keep the filenames in english.

Do I have to make this in .htaccess file? Or does WordPress have any built in functionality for this?

Comment: Update your question with the code you use to register the post type.

Comment: This is not a custom post type. This is a custom template for posts. It has been created just by creating the file single-schools.php with the comment `/* Template Name: Skolor */` in the top inside it.

Comment: Can you not just change your permalink structure?

Comment: The general permalink structure? How do you mean I should change it? I want the current structure. Just want to translate this template's permalink.

Comment: Permalinks aren't generated by a template, they are generated by your permalink structure/category & post slugs

Comment: Yes, but there must be a connection somewhere. Otherwise `/schools/post` wouldn't work. You say I have to change my permalink structure. In that case, I want to know exactly how I should change it? Sorry, but I need a more specific answer then just "change your permalink structure".

Comment: Edit: Think I got it to work now. Seems my schools template actually was a Page. So I could change the permalink there. And it also was a file called schools.php on the server (not local somehow) that I maybe created earlier and then removed. So I removed it from the server now anyway. To not cause any problem.